# Limit results of a joined table to the number of entries in the base table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use Lansweeper to keep track of all server assets.
At the moment I am working on a report, which shows which webservers are installed and running.
For this I have to join to tables, Table A contains the installed webserver software, table B contains the names of the services

The expected result should like this:

| VM | Version | Class | Servicename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VM1 | 9 | Tomcat | tomcat9 |
| VM2 | 9 | Tomcat | tomcat9 |
| VM2 | 7 | Tomcat | tomcat7 |
| VM3 | 9 | Tomcat | tomcat9 |

It is working fine, except for servers where multiple webservers are installed. If I have two webservers on a machine I get 4 results in the table. This is because I join based on the VM-ID, so the result looks like this:

| VM | Version | Class | Servicename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VM1 | 9 | Tomcat | tomcat9 |
| VM2 | 9 | Tomcat | tomcat9 |
| VM2 | 7 | Tomcat | tomcat7 |
| VM2 | **9** | Tomcat | **tomcat7** |
| VM2 | **7** | Tomcat | **tomcat9** |
| VM3 | 9 | Tomcat | tomcat9 |

This is the SQL statement for this result:

```
select a.VM, a.Version, a.Class, b.Servicename
from Installedsoftware as a
inner join Services as b on a.VM = b.VM
```

I totally understand that this happens because of two entries in table A und table B which results in 4 entries because of the join.

Is there a way to avoid this without adding a second join condition? Because this would only help in this scenario but not if I have two tomcat9 servers on the same machine.
Is there a way to limit the results in a way like "if Table A has only two entries for VM1, then show only two lines of the joined table"?

Comment: If there are two matches in B for a row in A, which row in B do you want?

Comment: If you want the highest version number try a `MAX` on the version with `GROUP BY` on the other fields.

Comment: in my situation it does not matter. So the first matching row is fine and ignore all rows afterwards

Comment: To SQL Server, it _does_ matter. There is no I_DONT_CARE_WHICH_ROW() function. :-)

Comment: i know (would be an awesome function btw ^^) but in my situation some rows are identical, if I have two Tomcat9 running on the same machine, the row in table B are identical. But on a machine with tomcat9 and tomcat7 the rows differ. So there is no general way to decide which row fits better. That is why I thought about the first row which is returned by table B

Comment: But still, what does "first" mean to you? Remember that in SQL Server a table is more like a bag of rows than a file.

Comment: Are the service names truly identical? If so, why not just do a ```GROUP BY a.VM, a.[Version], a.Class, b.Servicename```. Could even add a ```COUNT(*)``` to display the number of services which may be useful to your user

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Showing the results you want and the results you have is nice, but without the input data (with DDL) it's a bit more of a challenge to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This *seems* like a [groupwise-maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsql-server%5d%20and%20%5bgroupwise-maximum%5d&searchOn=3) problem, which has several potential approaches, but all encourage a *predictable, deterministic* row as opposed to "I don't care which row." One way is:

```
select a.VM, a.Version, a.Class, b.Servicename
from dbo.Installedsoftware as a
left outer join 
(
  SELECT VM, Servicename, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY VM ORDER BY Servicename)
  FROM dbo.Services
) as b on a.VM = b.VM
AND b.rn = 1;
```

You could get a little closer to "I don't care" by changing:

```
    (PARTITION BY VM ORDER BY @@SPID)
```

Or to a pseudo-random row (at a performance cost) using:

```
    (PARTITION BY VM ORDER BY NEWID())
```

Comment: Aaron B. --> you can also use (PARTITION BY VM ORDER BY (SELECT 1))

Comment: @Surendra You can, you can also say `ORDER BY (SELECT -1)` but is that any clearer or shorter? (FWIW `ORDER BY @@SPID` comes from [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/04/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-4))